# Centos 7 upgradink PHP 5.4 to PHP5.6

Tags: php, centos7

When runnning command to upgrade php:

```
yum install -y php56w
```

I'm getting error:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w.x86_64 0:5.6.25-1.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.25-1.w6 for package: php56w-5.6.25-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.25-1.w6 for package: php56w-5.6.25-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-cli = 5.6.25-1.w6 for package: php56w-5.6.25-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: php56w-5.6.25-1.w6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w.x86_64 0:5.6.25-1.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: php56w-5.6.25-1.w6.x86_64
---> Package php56w-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.25-1.w6 will be installed
---> Package php56w-common.x86_64 0:5.6.25-1.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: php56w-common-5.6.25-1.w6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php56w-5.6.25-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115
           Installed: httpd-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.4.x86_64 (@updates)
               httpd-mmn = 20120211
               httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
               httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
           Available: httpd-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.x86_64 (base)
               httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
               httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
               httpd-mmn = 20120211
           Available: httpd-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (updates)
               httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
               httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
               httpd-mmn = 20120211
Error: Package: php56w-common-5.6.25-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: libgmp.so.3()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Please comment only if you are know what offers, because it's live server.

Comment: You always run upgrades on live server without testing it first? Create VM copy of this server and try things there first. `--skip-broken` something tells me that this just might work but do not try it on production without test.

Comment: @E_p how I can make copy of this server to VM?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/223547/how-do-you-copy-a-physical-hard-drive-to-a-vmware-virtual-hard-disk

Comment: Is not suitable for me, I'm not using VMware

Comment: Another option install virtualbox create centos 7 vm from scratch yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experimented the same problem.
I clean cache and everithing goes ok. 
Good luck!

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum install -y php56w
```